# how to handle spaces within a Var when sending Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending a variable via **ajax**.

The values are indeed being sent succefuly

However, I encounter problems when i have a variable that is comprised of two words i.e:

```
var same time;
```

when the variable is received at the receiving end its rendered as:

```
same+time
```

i actually want the space to remain.

below is my ajax code. You can see that I have send the values as an object, so the space between the words should remain intact.

```
$('.same').click(function (e) {  

        e.preventDefault();  
var results = 'same time'; 
.......................

    $data = {ID: 1212,results:results,ip:ipAddress};

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/example_page.html',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:$data,  

            success: function(data){
              alert(data); 
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent("what ever")`. It will make it URL Friendly.

Comment: hey Void. thanks so much for the advice. i will give it a try tonight.